# Change VMware Number of Processor

Tags: cpu

I have laptop with core i7 CPU, I install VMware on it I want know If I change number of processor to 2 is it really use 2 of my core i7 core or just use one and simulate me in VMware I have 2 cpu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using 2 of the cores on your computer.

Comment: ...a dual core i7?